# How to add a post with new Taxonomy without assigning to default category?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, customization

I need your help, I have created new Taxonomy in WordPress (Called Sources) and whenever I create new post and select that new Taxonomy WordPress forces to assign Default category.

How to disable WordPress from assigning default category to posts with already assigned another taxonomy (Sources)?

Comment: You can't. Taxonomies are not assigned to posts, only terms in a taxonomy are assigned. If you can explain what you are trying to do there may be a way to accomplish your goal without fighting with the WordPress Core.

Answer (score 0):

Posts and Categories are tied together. Your best bet is creating custom post type that supports only your taxonomy. This way, your posts (which are now under your custom post type) will not have any conflict with wordpress assigning default category.

If you explain your scenario with more details, I will be in better position to help you.

Comment: Thanks Ruturaj for your answer, but I cannot unfortunately use that fix.

Comment: Let me tell you in details:
1- We are News aggregator
2- We are using WordPress plugin to post automatically to database.
3- We post news to custom Taxonomy not to category.